# Count cells with a specific word in cell array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

Suppose that we have this cell array :

```
X = {'Good' 'Bad' 'Good'; 
     'Bad' 'Good' 'Bad'; 
     'Bad' 'Bad' 'Bad'; 
     'Good' 'Bad' 'Good'; 
     'Good' 'Good' 'Good'};
```

How can I count occurrences of `Good` and `Bad` in every row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have equal number of elements or cells per row in such an input cell array, a fast solution for count of `{'Good'}` cells per row -

```
count = sum(strcmp(X,{'Good'}),2)
```

Use the same rule for `{'Bad'}`.

---

If `strcmp` drags you slow, you can use `char` instead with my personal favorite `bsxfun`.

For `{'Good'}` -

```
Xchar = char(X{:})
count = sum(reshape(all(bsxfun(@eq,Xchar(:,1:numel('Good')),'Good'),2),size(X)),2)
```

For `{'Bad'}` -

```
count = sum(reshape(all(bsxfun(@eq,Xchar(:,1:numel('Bad')),'Bad'),2),size(X)),2)
```

Comment: In general, you need to count `n-1` times, where `n` is the number of unique words in your list. In this example, the occurrence of `'Bad'` are simply the total number of elements in a row - occurrences of `'Good'`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov That's right for the given input, but since it was not mentioned that those two words are the only words here, it makes sense to keep the solutions a little more generic. Appreciate the observation there though!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count whole strings, rather than words.

You can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to obtain unique strings and integer labels, each label corresponding to a string. You then only need to count how many times each label appears, which can be done using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (or [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html)):

```
[str, ~, lab] = unique(X);
cnt = sum(bsxfun(@eq, lab(:), 1:max(lab))).'; %'// Or: cnt = histc(lab, 1:max(lab))
```

Result:

```
str = 
    'Bad'
    'Good'

cnt =
     7
     8
```